# checking if a html element is true with ruby and watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

at the moment I have this:

```
def burnChart()
   @browser.div(:id => "container").div(:id => "header").img(:class => "cogMenuHover").click
   @browser.div(:id => "container").div(:id => "header").div(:class => "sbTopMenu").li(:class => "taskMenuOp", :index =>1).click

  if 
    assert(@browser.send(type.to_sym, :class, "highcharts-grid").exists?)
    puts 'Chart has been found!'
  else
    puts 'No chart was generated'
  end
end
```

originally I thought I had to use to_css? but from what I've seen of others using it, that's incorrect I'm unsure.

Can anyone help me out, I just want to check if a class exists and return a true or fasle to log an error or a confirmation

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, is there a reason you're not just doing a regular @browser.element(:how => :what).present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
def burnChart()
   @browser.div(:id => "container").div(:id => "header").img(:class => "cogMenuHover").click
   @browser.div(:id => "container").div(:id => "header").div(:class => "sbTopMenu").li(:class => "taskMenuOp", :index =>1).click

  #Due to using IE, it looks like .exists? has to be used.
  if @browser.element(:class, "highcharts-grid").exists?
    puts 'Chart has been found!'
  else
    puts 'No chart was generated'
  end
end
```

Notice that:

- The check for the element should be the condition for the if statement.
- Changed the check to be `.present?`. `.exists?` returns true as long as the element is on the page, but usually you also want to check that it is visible.
- The switch to `@browser.element` instead of `@browser.send`. You can do what you were doing, but you were not defining a `type` anywhere, so seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Seems to almost work, I don't get an error in the console anymore, but it logs that no chart was found, even though it is definitely there? I don't know if it's an issue that it's an svg generated chart, the tags used by it are <g class=highchart-grid"></g>, would that maybe the problem?

Comment: I tried a page with that tag and it seems to work. My guess would be a timing issue. If you run the .present? line manually through irb, does it work for the chart?

Comment: it returns false, how odd.

@browser.element(:class, "highcharts-grid").present?
 =>false

Comment: Is the chart in a frame or iframe?

Comment: surprising not.  It's all generated through javascript on the page itself.  No frames or iframes.. so odd.

Comment: Is the page you are testing public or do you know a page that has the same problem?

Comment: Try using an Xpath to find it.  @browser.element(:xpath, "//g[@class='highcharts-grid']").present? instead.  Using the demo site (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic/grid) and the latest Watir classic TRUE was returned.  Check this with IRB, then implement it in your script with a sleep / something smarter.

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with how each browser interprets the visibility of the element. In Firefox (watir-webdriver), `.present?` returns true. In IE (watir-classic or webdriver), it returns false. If you switch to `.exists?`, it will return true in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info guys, I'll try it on Monday, I can't right now because I'm not at work, I'll keep you posted shortly!

Comment: @JustinKO I found the issue, in irb it now returns true, but the reason why I was having issues is because it's automated testing.  previous to the chart there is a view of a table, then to view the table it, it opens up in a new tab.

Any ideas on how to tell watir which tab is being used in chrome and firefox?